# ASP.NET 5 access context or request information at ConfigureServices in Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to access Context or Request information at the time ConfigureServices method is called in the Startup class?

What I would like to do is to decide what Facebook or MS authentication info to load from Database based on URL or other request info.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Entity Framework services to the services container.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Configure the options for the authentication middleware.
        // You can add options for Google, Twitter and other middleware as shown below.
        // For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        services.Configure<FacebookAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
            options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        });

        services.Configure<MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientSecret"];
        });
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup is for configuration that happens once per application, not once per request. If you need to do something on a per-request basis, you should either do it in a MVC/API controller or middleware.

Comment: in that case, we can Facebook and MS authentication services be registered outside of the ConfigureServices method? because the way they are in the pre-built template is useless if you want to make it multi-tenant!

Comment: Are you talking about a case where one tenant would have FB auth while another would have MS auth, but not both at the same time?

Comment: No, it is more that the credentials (token etc) for FB or MS would be different tenant to tenant.

Comment: In that case, I suspect your best alternative is to write a modified version of the middleware that can take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

The current `HttpContext` is set by the [hosting engine](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Internal/HostingEngine.cs#L78.).

A [few lines](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Internal/HostingEngine.cs#L65) before that the engine builds the application, that means `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are already called before the `HttpContext` is available.

This makes sense, because the application configuration in the `Startup` class is only called when the application starts, not every request.

Comment: in that case, we can Facebook and MS authentication services be registered outside of the ConfigureServices method? because the way they are in the pre-built template is useless if you want to make it multi-tenant!